# What are the main gotras and the upagotras among Brahmins?

Tags: vedas, brahmins, gotra

I would like to know the names of the original gotras. I have seen online different lists of gotras (sometimes up to 100+). I would like to know if there is a tree diagram of gotras and upagotras anywhere.

Comment: Matsya purana Chapter 195 to 202 states many of them. See [this](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.45858/page/n206/mode/1up)

Comment: I've noticed that the  Jamadagnya-Vatsa-s are a major clan of brahmins (including the popular Sri-vatsa, Jamadagni, and Vatsa gotras).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading the The Early Brahmanical System of Gotra and Pravara by by John Brough.

https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/The_Early_Brahmanical_System_of_Gotra_an/QZhtAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0

The major clans are the Bhrigu-s, the Angiras-es (Gautamas, Bharadvajas, and the Kevala Angiras-es), the Atri-s, the Vishwamitra-s, the Kashyapa-s, and the Vasishta-s.

Answer (score -2):

Brahmins (Vaishnva) following the Srimad Bhagavatam (a.k.a. 5th veda) must give up all other gotras and accept only acyuta-gotra. Edit - Which is of the Brahma sampradaya. https://vedabase.io/en/library/transcripts/721002sbla/?query=Gotra#bb207811

Tree with 3000 Srimad Bhagavatam cited names in one free PDF, 6 feet x 16 ft (1.8 m x 4.6 metres) http://www.dandavats.com/?p=81179
1970s tree http://vedadev.ru/images/SB%20Family%20Tree03.jpg

Comment: never heard of acyuta-gotra.  South Indian Iyengars have pretty much the same gotras ar Smartas - like vatoola, kaushika, bharadwaja, atreya etc,

Comment: @Sarvabhouma add a hyphen or space to Upa for google to recognise it.