# Do the total number of gotras change?

Tags: scripture, gotra

There are two related and interesting questions on this site

[Number and Types of Gotras](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33867/number-and-types-of-gotras)

[What are the main gotras and the upagotras among Brahmins?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9254/what-are-the-main-gotras-and-the-upagotras-among-brahmins)

I don't know whether gotras are creatable or not? I mean, is it true that the number of gotras can increase by time or the list of gotras is constant?

Comment: Matsya purana Chapter 195 to 202 has some info on gotras. Idk if it really answers any of the two questions linked. Someone intrested look [this](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.45858/page/n206/mode/1up)